# Error in Maven goal inside Jenkins on Docker in Windows

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, maven-3

I am trying to setup jenkins on docker in my windows machine. Everything was going smooth until I configured the maven goal in Jenkins. It looks like maven is overlooking the Jenkins_home path configured while starting the docker. I used the following command during startup

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v //D/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home Jenkins

I also tried the following

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home://D/jenkins_workspace jenkins

but I keep getting the error

[crazywebapp_dev] $ mvn clean install

> FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: error=2, No such
>   file or directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)   at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) Caused:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory
>   "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/crazywebapp_dev"): error=2, No such file
>   or directory  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:249)

I believe it has got to do something with maven because the Jenkins workspace is getting created in my D: drive and the code is checked out successfully from bit bucket and the workspace contents shows up in Jenkins. I have also noticed that even though the workspace is created in my D: drive, Jenkins_home still shows up as /var/Jenkins_home in the Jenkins config page. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: The issue is located here: ` Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/crazywebapp_dev"): error=2, No such file or directory at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) at `.. That means your jenkins can't find the `mvn` program. This means Maven is not correctly configured in your jenkins tools configuration..

Comment: @khmarbaise . Thank you. That is exactly what it was . I was expecting an error more in term of "This command does not exist" and misunderstood the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have also noticed that even though the workspace is created in my
>   D: drive, Jenkins_home still shows up as /var/Jenkins_home in the
>   Jenkins config page. Please help me figure this out.

From the containers perspective, there is no D: drive, the jenkins_home will always be `/var/jenkins_home` inside the container.

The syntax `-v //D/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home` means mount D:\jenkins onto /var/jenkins_home inside the container. This will effectively just replace or backup the containers jenkins home in the jenkins folder.

The syntax `-v jenkins_home://D/jenkins_workspace` is not useful. It means "create" a /D/jenkins_workspace directory inside the container and use a named volume called `jenkins_home` to backup this folder. This is not useful.

The main problem that you have, is that maven is not installed inside the **jenkins container**. Thus jenkins clearly can't find it. You need to configure maven to be installed. You can do that in jenkins, by going to:

`Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Maven section` and then configure it to install maven automatically.

Comment: Wow. I am learning docker and misunderstood the whole thing. Thanks a lot for clearing this up. Everything is setup now.